# Realizar Notificaciones por mail en Genexus 15

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Como están? quisiera preguntarles cual es el protocolo o método habitual, por el cual se realiza normalmente las notificaciones por mail en Genexus, estoy trabajando en Genexus 15 U9, generador Java.
Desde ya muchas gracias!!
Saludos!!

Comment: Gustavo El mas habitual son los tipos de datos mail y smtp, son complementares.

Comment: Hola Sandro! Gracias por responder!, he tratado de enviar el mail, pero al momento de enviarlo, tuve el sigte código de error: SEND Codigo de Error de ENVIO: 10 --->>>>Descripcion del Error ENVIO: Error sending message - Invalid Addresses. La dirección del remitente como el del destinatario estan correctamente definidas. Tienes alguna idea de este error?. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

En GeneXus tienes disponible el [tipo de datos `SMTPSession`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6937,SMTPSession%20Data%20Type,) que permite enviar e-mails.

Por ejemplo, de esta forma(*):

```
Event 'Send'
    &AddressTo.Address = 'isidoro@cañones.com'
    &AddressTo.Name = 'Isidoro Cañones'
    &Send.To.Clear()
    &Send.To.Add(&AddressTo)

    &Send.Subject = 'You’re invited to my party'
    &Send.HTMLText = 'Next Saturday I celebrate my birthday, do not miss it!'

    // The SMTP server used in this case does not need authentication.
    &MessageSMTP.Host = 'SMTP Server'

    &MessageSMTP.Sender.Name = 'Patoruzu'
    &MessageSMTP.Sender.Address = 'patoruzu@hotmail.com'

    &MessageSMTP.Authentication = 1
    &MessageSMTP.UserName = 'My user'
    &MessageSMTP.Password = 'My password'
    &MessageSMTP.Login()

    &MessageSMTP.Send(&Send) 

    if &MessageSMTP.ErrCode <> 0
        msg(&MessageSMTP.ErrDescription)
    endif   
    &MessageSMTP.Logout()
EndEvent
```

(*) ejemplo tomado del documento [Data Types for Email handling](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15710,Data%20Types%20for%20Email%20handling,) (en inglés, no oficial...)